# How to sort results select2 tags alphabetically?

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2

I would like to sort alphabetically (case insensitive), the tags choosen from a select2.
I have used the sorter function to sort the tags to be selected but once selected they are not displayed alphabetically.

How to do this ? (I work with last 4.0.13 select2 release).

```
$('#example1').select2({
        tags: true,
        multiple: true,
        allowClear: true,
        sorter: function(data) {
                return data.sort(function (a, b) {
                        var a1 = a.text.toLowerCase();
                        var b1 = b.text.toLowerCase();
                        if (a1 > b1) {
                            return 1;
                        }
                        if (a1 < b1) {
                            return -1;
                        }
                        return 0;
                });
        }
});
```

```
<select name="list" id="example1" style="width:500px;">
   <option>United States</option>
   <option>Austria</option>
   <option>Alabama</option>
   <option>Jamaica</option>
   <option>Taiwan</option>
   <option>canada</option>
   <option>palau</option>
   <option>Wyoming</option>
</select>
```

[image]

Should be Alabama, Austria, Jamaica, United States.

Comment: Looks like `sorter` only sorts the options, but not the actually selected values. I can't find anything else in the docs, that sounds like it would do what you want - so I guess you might have to _get_ the selected values first, then remove them all, and add them again in properly sorted order ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok the only way I have found to have ordered tags once selected is to order them when you populate the select2.

Here is a jsFiddle that demonstrates the solution: https://jsfiddle.net/PBrockmann/x42sqg76/

```
var tags = [
  "United States",
  "Austria",
  "Alabama",
  "Jamaica",
  "Taiwan",
  "Canada",
  "Palau",
  "Wyoming"
];

tags.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a.toLowerCase().localeCompare(b.toLowerCase());
});

var options = [];
for (var i = 0; i < tags.length; i++) {
  options.push({
    id: tags[i],
    text: tags[i]
  });
}

$('#example1').select2({
  data: options,
  tags: true,
  multiple: true,
  allowClear: true,
  placeholder: 'select...',
});
```

New tags (not existing in the preset list) appear at the end but this is a behviour I accept.

Answer (score 2):

That was not trivial

Here I sort the container when selecting

```js
const normalize = str => {
  str = str.replace(/\s+/g,"");
  return str === ""? "" : str.toLowerCase();
};  

$('#example1').select2({
  tags: true,
  multiple: true,
  allowClear: true
});
$('#example1').on("select2:select", function() {
  const $container = $("#select2-example1-container");
  const $lis = $("li", $container)
  $lis.sort((a, b) => normalize(a.getAttribute("title")).localeCompare(normalize(b.getAttribute("title"))))
    .appendTo($container)


});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<select name="list" id="example1" multiple="multiple" style="width:500px">
  <option>United States</option>
  <option>Austria</option>
  <option>Alabama</option>
  <option>Jamaica</option>
  <option>Taiwan</option>
  <option>canada</option>
  <option>New York</option>
  <option>Newark</option>
  <option>palau</option>
  <option>Wyoming</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Woauh, nice. 
2 notes. First, it works with last 4.1.0-rc.0 not with 4.0.13 I was using.
Second, what is the purpose of using a normalize function ? Remove space ? Why ?

Comment: See New York, it should come after Newark no?

Comment: Tested in my code. It does not work properly. Do not understand why. The order is not correct at the initialization. Please try: https://jsfiddle.net/PBrockmann/x42sqg76/
Just add 'BBBB', then the order will be correct. Otherwiser 'AAAA' is at the end !

Comment: I have no idea. There is no interesting events to use. I tried but failed https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/tg6f9rux/

Comment: I think the sorter method is only for options to be selected. In your example you cannot select any once you have set `sorter: sort`

Comment: It made no difference

Comment: Yes, I am surprise that this behaviour of having sorted selected tags cannot be achieved easilly.

Comment: Also posted on https://forums.select2.org/t/how-to-sort-results-select2-tags-alphabetically